# Salesforce Platform Integration User Unable to Access "external credential"

Tags: salesforce

I am Publishing a custom Platform Event 'OrderSummaryPrescribedEvent__e' and an Apex Trigger 'OrderSummaryPrescribedTrigger' listening is Queuing Apex Job 'FindPharmacy'. FindPharmacy is callout external service using 'Named Credential'.

Error i'm getting is "System.CalloutException: We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "Motivated" might not exist."

Debug log shows user handling queuing is 'Platform Integration User' with a User ID that doesn't exist under Setup -> Users. This looks like a classic case of missing 'permission set' but i'm not sure how to address this as the User doesn't exist under Users.

Would appreciate any help.

I'm not so sure why solution to try here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally triggers that handle platform events run as dedicated "Automated User" special account. If you see somebody else running the trigger's code (or if you want to change that to run as one of sysadmins that has the required permission sets, licenses to managed packages etc) - you can override it. It's done with a special metadata api file, you can't do it in UI.

Read up https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm

Maybe start by trying to (tooling api) query `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`. Check what you have now (if it's not in your project/git already) and if needed - deploy the override. From what I remember you'll have to deactivate and then start the trigger/subscription again for it to pick fresh config.